# How can I get a fixed address-bar in Google Chrome for Android with javascript

Tags: java, jquery, html

http://s7.picofile.com/file/8388260676/photo.jpg

When I click "No. 1", The page shows like a Nav-Mobile (No. 2);
But when I go "up/down-touch/move" on the "No. 3",
Address-bar (No. 4) is disabled in Google Chrome (Android Phone).
The load address is fixed in Google Chrome. (Like Website: Alibaba.com)
I want the address bar No. 6 to not be moved,
When I go up and down in  No. 5. 
I added the following code in CSS, But it doesn't work.

```
position:fixed;
width: 100%;
height:100%
float:left;
```

How can I get a fixed address-bar in Google Chrome for Android with javascript?

Comment: The exception is with position:fixed; in this case, can you try to add "width: 100%;
height:100%;" to body. And remove position:fixed; ? If you can't please share more details about your layout and the script doing the collapse effect.

Comment: I did not understand. Can you create a project for me on jsfiddle .net?

Comment: :root {
   --app-height: 100%;
}

html,
body {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;

    @media not all and (hover:hover) {
        height: var(--app-height);
    }
}

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this code below:

```
<style type="text/css">
  html, body {margin: 0; height: 100%; overflow: hidden}
</style>
```

Comment: this only works if you don't want to able to scroll on the page.