# click nav on position fixed with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this CSS code by: 
[How can I get a fixed address-bar in Google Chrome for Android with javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60241559/how-can-i-get-a-fixed-address-bar-in-google-chrome-for-android-with-javascript)

Here is the preview image:
http://s7.picofile.com/file/8388260676/photo.jpg

When I scroll down the page, The code shows **< main style="top:2268px;" >** ;

But when I click number one, The code shows **< main style="top:0px;" >**

I want it to be **2268px** when I click it.

My code (javascript):

```
$(window).scroll(function (event) {
    var sc = $(window).scrollTop();
    // console.log(sc);
    $("body main").css('top',sc);
});
$("header .nav-click").click(function(){
    $("body main").css('top',sc);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `var cs` is local variable. if you want to use it in another function,try to initialize it in the global scope.

Also, You should define it in 'px'. mean add `px` at the end when you assign it as css

```
var sc = $(window).scrollTop();

$(window).scroll(function (event) {
    sc = $(window).scrollTop();
    $("body main").css('top',sc + 'px');
});

$("header .nav-click").click(function(){
    $("body main").css('top',sc + 'px');
});
```

Comment: it didn't work and it gets **"top:0px"**
I think because of this code **"position:fixed"** and
If I change this code **"position:unset"**
Shows this code **"top:2268px"**